# Migration to Swift 3

Tags: swift3

I have a variable called service, like so:

```
var service: AnyObject = [] //Swift 2.3
```

My question is how to migrate this to Swift 3. I'm a noob in iOS, I've looked in Internet but could't get it.

PS. I get an error "Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with array literal"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you were doing was always wrong. If you have no value to supply at initialization time, use an Optional. Ideally you should declare this as the actual type of value that it will be when gets a value (rather than a catch-all type such as AnyObject). But if you can't do that, then just use `Any?`:

```
var service : Any?
```

Or, if this thing's type *is* known — for example, if you know it's going to be a Dictionary — then declare it *as* a Dictionary, possibly by supplying an empty Dictionary, like this:

```
var service = [AnyHashable:Any]()
```

Comment: Thanks man, but now I'm getting "Type 'Any?' has no subscript members"

Comment: So you lied to the other answerer. It _is_ an array. Why didn't you accept his answer?

Comment: Because it is not an array, that's why

Comment: Then why are you trying to subscript it? You have not shown the code where you attempt to do that, so I don't know whether you imagine it is an array or a dictionary. But it must be supposedly one of those, or you would not be doing that. Please keep in mind that all of this is based on one line of code which sucked to start with. If you really want help, _show your code_. Show what `service` really is and how it is used. You are just making everybody guess.

Comment: Hey matt, easy man, remember I'm new in this iOS stuff. The thing is I'm using this service variable as a dictionary but in Swift 2 it could be declared as an empty object, that's why I though it should be needed the declaration.

Comment: But you're not new at cooperation and communication — yet you still haven't give the further code I've requested.

Comment: Anyway, now that you have finally _revealed_, like a magician producing a rabbit from a hat, that this is supposed to be a dictionary, I have edited my answer to show you how to do it. But please note that your _original_ code was never for a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

`var service = [AnyObject]()` will work.

Comment: I think this way is for an array, mine is just a variable but i need to initialize it when I declare it, but this way is not working anymore in Swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using it in Swift -3

```
var service = [AnyObject]()  //Swift 3
service = ["a" as AnyObject,"b" as AnyObject]
print(service)
```

Output:

```
a,b
```